# Pythonj json.update

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a dictionary:

```py
dict = {'1': None, '2': None, '3': None, '4': None, '5': None, '6': None, '7': None, '8': None, '9': None, '10': None}
```

Whenever I try to update the file with:

```py
with open('test.json', 'w+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data.update(dict)
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

The output file looks like this:

```json
{}
{
  "1": null,
  "2": null,
  "3": null,
  "4": null,
  "5": null,
  "6": null,
  "7": null,
  "8": null,
  "9": null,
  "10": null
}
```

How can I put the dictionary inside the first curly braces? (my initial json file looks like this `{}`

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code but the program encountered an error at the line `data = json.load(f)` because you just open file to write. If you open file to write, the file will be cleared. You should open file to read and load json first, then open file to write and dump json. I also recommend that you shouldn't use keywork to name variable because this will cause some serious bugs.

Comment: I changed it to `with open('test.json', 'w+') as f:`

Answer (score 0):

Open the file ==> Make changes ==> Save the file

```
import json

dict = {'1': None, '2': None, '3': None, '4': None, '5': None, '6': None, '7': None, '8': None, '9': None, '10': None}
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#  Do something with the data
dict['1'] = 100

with open('test.json', 'wt') as f:
    data.update(dict)
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: isnt this the same thing OP did?

Comment: Observe  the 'w' in open(). The file was opened to be written to while the first statement json.load(f) reads the file.

Comment: the only difference is the `wt` in open, which, I don't think does anything different. This would work however, this is a very long way of doing it when it could be compressed into just 5 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this error before, what worked for me is using `seek(0)` before writing to the file. Like this:

```py
with open('test.json', 'w+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data.update(dict)
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

`json.load` reads the file entirely and puts the file position at the end of the file. Thats why `json.dump` writes to the end of the file, the file position is at the end, and `json.dump` picks it up from there, and writes to the end of the file.